# Prevent default function using only child pseudo selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am using jQuery to dynamically add elements every time a user clicks a link (".add-event"). Also included in this element is a icon to remove the entire element if the user chooses. I want to hide or disable this remove icon if the element is the last left on the page. This is what I have tried so far:

```
$(document).on('click','.close_box2:only-child',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

AND

```
if( $('.event').length===1) {
    $('.close_box2').hide()
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="event">
    <span class="close_box2"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
     <span class="add-event">Add Event</span>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong!? Thanks

Comment: At least the second one works: http://jsfiddle.net/KPY9r/

Comment: Wow good call, I must have some other error or conflict on my page that is preventing this from working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/KPY9r/6/

You just want to check for the "last one" inside the delete handler:

```
// initial hide of sole close button
$('.close_box2').hide();

// On add, clone the template and show all close buttons
$(document).on('click', '.add-event', function () {
    // Create a new event based on the template
    $('#events').append($('#template').html());
    // Show all close buttons (as we must now have > 1 event)
    $('.close_box2').show();
});

$(document).on('click', '.close_box2', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.event').remove();
    // Is there only one left?
    if ($('.event').length === 1) {
        // Hide the close box on the last event
        $('.close_box2').hide()
    }
});
```

**Notes:**

- I use a dummy `<script>` element to hold you HTML template. This is better than cloning an element on the page and much better than inline HTML strings in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The following looks better regarding performance:

```
$('.close_box2:only-child').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Performance where? This takes longer to connect as it performs a search "up front" and results in multiple handlers, whereas the delegated `on` they used connects a single handler to `document` at lightning speed (and you do not care about a minuscule delay at event time as you can't click fast enough to notice!) :)